# STM32F429 Discovery - Unable to Use SPI with DMA for driving WS2812B LEDs

Tags: stm32, spi, led, dma, stm32f4discovery

I have setup a project using STM32CubeIDE to use with my STM32F429I-DISC1 Discovery board.
I would like to use it to drive an array of WS2812B LED modules, which requires a single data line at a high frequency.

I would like to use SPI with DMA in order to transfer the data continuously to the WS2812B LED modules.

What I have currently (Having messed around a little bit to see what might be wrong):

**main.c**

```c
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under Ultimate Liberty license
  * SLA0044, the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with
  * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                             www.st.com/SLA0044
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
CRC_HandleTypeDef hcrc;

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c3;

RNG_HandleTypeDef hrng;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi4;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi5;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi4_tx;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

SDRAM_HandleTypeDef hsdram1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_CRC_Init(void);
static void MX_FMC_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI5_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_RNG_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI4_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_CRC_Init();
  MX_FMC_Init();
  MX_I2C3_Init();
  MX_SPI5_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_RNG_Init();
  MX_SPI4_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  // Setting up DMA myself?
  hdma_spi4_tx.Instance = DMA2_Stream1;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_1;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
  hdma_spi4_tx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
  HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi4_tx);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  uint8_t LEDData_WS2812B[][3] = {
    {0x92, 0x49, 0x24}, {0x92, 0x49, 0x24}, {0xDB, 0x6D, 0xB6}
  };
  uint8_t LEDData[][3] = { // RGB format
    {0x00, 0x00, 0xFF}
  };

  HAL_DMA_Start(&hdma_spi4_tx, (uint32_t)LEDData_WS2812B, (uint32_t)&hspi4.Instance->DR, sizeof(LEDData_WS2812B)/sizeof(uint8_t));
  HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi4, (uint8_t *)LEDData_WS2812B, sizeof(LEDData_WS2812B)/sizeof(uint8_t));

  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 160;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 8;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief CRC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CRC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 1 */
  hcrc.Instance = CRC;
  if (HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CRC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END CRC_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief I2C3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 1 */
  hi2c3.Instance = I2C3;
  hi2c3.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c3.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c3.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c3, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c3, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief RNG Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RNG_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RNG_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RNG_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RNG_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RNG_Init 1 */
  hrng.Instance = RNG;
  if (HAL_RNG_Init(&hrng) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RNG_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RNG_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI4 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI4_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI4_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI4_Init 1 */
  /* SPI4 parameter configuration*/
  hspi4.Instance = SPI4;
  hspi4.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi4.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi4.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi4.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi4.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi4.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi4.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
  hspi4.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi4.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi4.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi4.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI4_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI4_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI5 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI5_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 1 */
  /* SPI5 parameter configuration*/
  hspi5.Instance = SPI5;
  hspi5.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi5.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi5.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi5.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi5.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_16;
  hspi5.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi5.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream1_IRQn);

}

/* FMC initialization function */
static void MX_FMC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 0 */

  FMC_SDRAM_TimingTypeDef SdramTiming = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 1 */

  /** Perform the SDRAM1 memory initialization sequence
  */
  hsdram1.Instance = FMC_SDRAM_DEVICE;
  /* hsdram1.Init */
  hsdram1.Init.SDBank = FMC_SDRAM_BANK2;
  hsdram1.Init.ColumnBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_COLUMN_BITS_NUM_8;
  hsdram1.Init.RowBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_ROW_BITS_NUM_12;
  hsdram1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FMC_SDRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
  hsdram1.Init.InternalBankNumber = FMC_SDRAM_INTERN_BANKS_NUM_4;
  hsdram1.Init.CASLatency = FMC_SDRAM_CAS_LATENCY_3;
  hsdram1.Init.WriteProtection = FMC_SDRAM_WRITE_PROTECTION_DISABLE;
  hsdram1.Init.SDClockPeriod = FMC_SDRAM_CLOCK_PERIOD_2;
  hsdram1.Init.ReadBurst = FMC_SDRAM_RBURST_DISABLE;
  hsdram1.Init.ReadPipeDelay = FMC_SDRAM_RPIPE_DELAY_1;
  /* SdramTiming */
  SdramTiming.LoadToActiveDelay = 2;
  SdramTiming.ExitSelfRefreshDelay = 7;
  SdramTiming.SelfRefreshTime = 4;
  SdramTiming.RowCycleDelay = 7;
  SdramTiming.WriteRecoveryTime = 3;
  SdramTiming.RPDelay = 2;
  SdramTiming.RCDDelay = 2;

  if (HAL_SDRAM_Init(&hsdram1, &SdramTiming) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler( );
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN FMC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END FMC_Init 2 */
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, NCS_MEMS_SPI_Pin|CSX_Pin|OTG_FS_PSO_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ACP_RST_GPIO_Port, ACP_RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, RDX_Pin|WRX_DCX_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, LD3_Pin|LD4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PF6 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : ENABLE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ENABLE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(ENABLE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : NCS_MEMS_SPI_Pin CSX_Pin OTG_FS_PSO_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = NCS_MEMS_SPI_Pin|CSX_Pin|OTG_FS_PSO_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : B1_Pin MEMS_INT1_Pin MEMS_INT2_Pin TP_INT1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin|MEMS_INT1_Pin|MEMS_INT2_Pin|TP_INT1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : B5_Pin VSYNC_Pin G2_Pin R4_Pin
                           R5_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B5_Pin|VSYNC_Pin|G2_Pin|R4_Pin
                          |R5_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : ACP_RST_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ACP_RST_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(ACP_RST_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : OTG_FS_OC_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_OC_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(OTG_FS_OC_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : R3_Pin R6_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = R3_Pin|R6_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : BOOT1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = BOOT1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(BOOT1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : G4_Pin G5_Pin B6_Pin B7_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = G4_Pin|G5_Pin|B6_Pin|B7_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : OTG_HS_ID_Pin OTG_HS_DM_Pin OTG_HS_DP_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_HS_ID_Pin|OTG_HS_DM_Pin|OTG_HS_DP_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_OTG_HS_FS;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : VBUS_HS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VBUS_HS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(VBUS_HS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : TE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = TE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(TE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : RDX_Pin WRX_DCX_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RDX_Pin|WRX_DCX_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : R7_Pin DOTCLK_Pin B3_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = R7_Pin|DOTCLK_Pin|B3_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : HSYNC_Pin G6_Pin R2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = HSYNC_Pin|G6_Pin|R2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : G7_Pin B2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = G7_Pin|B2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : G3_Pin B4_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = G3_Pin|B4_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD3_Pin LD4_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD3_Pin|LD4_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I get absolutely nothing on pin PE6 (SPI4_MOSI), and have been watching using a Digilent Analog Discovery 2:

[image: SPI4_MOSI signal with no changes observed]

One issue I believe I have found, is that DMA was not being initialized using the parameters I provided in STM32CubeMX screen of the IDE, so I included them manually. This, however, did not solve the issue, and is still the same.

I also found a website essentially doing what I am attempting to do using the same MCU I am, but cannot see where I'm going wrong:
https://microtechnics.ru/en/stm32cube-spi-and-dma-example/

**Thank you in advance for any help with this!!**

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to low reputation, but aren't you sending one single signal out? That might only make them flash for a split-second. These LEDs by themselves do not have 'On/Off' switches. Shouldn't you put `HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA` inside `while (1)` to send it continuously?

```
HAL_DMA_Start(&hdma_spi4_tx, (uint32_t)LEDData_WS2812B, (uint32_t)&hspi4.Instance->DR, sizeof(LEDData_WS2812B)/sizeof(uint8_t));

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi4, (uint8_t *)LEDData_WS2812B, sizeof(LEDData_WS2812B)/sizeof(uint8_t));
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

And think about what kind of signal you are sending to your LEDs. An array of LEDs has to be driven by a continuous Pulse-Width Modulated signal. Signal shape depends on LED characteristics like number of LEDs, power, RGB etc.

I have a stripe of LEDs close to yours (WS2813), though I have driven it with Arduino, not STM32. I required a special library to drive my LEDs called FastLED, which did PWM for me. Maybe you can take a look at it and port parts you need to C:

http://fastled.io/;
https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED

Or do it yourself. Doing PWM manually is not too hard, it's just arithmetic. STM324xx provides all tools necessary. Enable your TIM timers with CubeMX and set to PWM generation.
[image: CubeMX TIM setting]
Then create the signal by manipulating Configuration Settings (Pulse, Counter Settings, Prescaler, Counter Period) and clock configuration following data sheet for LEDs. They describe driving signal there:
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf

Lastly, here's some ancient code written in ArduinoIDE. This doesn't have  much to do with your question but have it anyway. It's supposed to make a flowing rainbow I think :-)

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_PIN     7   /*What pin to use*/
#define NUM_LEDS    30  /*how many leds in array*/
#define STD_DELAY   50  /*delay until next step in ms*/
#define MIN_VAL     16  /*lowest value RGB can take 0-255*/
#define MAX_VAL     128 /*highest value RGB can take 0-255*/        
#define STEP        8   /*how quickly to change colour (must follow eq. STEP = 2^n (where n is a natural number)*/

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() { /*set up leds*/
    FastLED.addLeds<WS2813, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
    unsigned char i = 0;
    unsigned char j = 0;
    unsigned char buf;
    unsigned char R=MAX_VAL;
    unsigned char G=MIN_VAL;
    unsigned char B=MIN_VAL;
    leds[NUM_LEDS-1] = CRGB(MIN_VAL,MIN_VAL,MIN_VAL);
    while (1){
        if (R == MAX_VAL && G < MAX_VAL && B == MIN_VAL){
            G += STEP;
        }
        else if (R > MIN_VAL && G == MAX_VAL && B == MIN_VAL){
            R -= STEP;
        }
        else if (R == MIN_VAL && G == MAX_VAL && B < MAX_VAL){
            B += STEP;
        }
        else if (R == MIN_VAL && G > MIN_VAL && B == MAX_VAL){
            G -= STEP;
        }
        else if (R < MAX_VAL && G == MIN_VAL && B == MAX_VAL){
            R += STEP;
        }
        else if (R == MAX_VAL && G == MIN_VAL && B > MIN_VAL){
            B -= STEP;
        }
        leds[0] = CRGB(R,G,B);
        for (j = NUM_LEDS-1; j > 0; j--){
            leds[j] = leds[j-1];
        }
        FastLED.show(); /*send signal to LEDs*/
        delay(STD_DELAY);

    }
}
```

Comment: There are a few libraries for STM32 to drive WS2812B chips, but I'd really like to do it myself. How I understand this is able to work, is that the DMA Controller will send a stream of data to the SPI interface to output over the single pin. With the 2.5 Mbit/s baud rate, it should output with the correct pulse widths according to the datasheet. With this way of doing things, the processor is completely free to do other things.